# How do I check a registry image creation date without pulling it for a CI CD incremental build

Tags: docker, image, timestamp, manifest

I want to cancel a CI CD build if none of the files changed that would go into a docker image.

For that I want to get the creation timestamp of a docker image without pulling it first.

```
docker pull groovy:latest
docker image inspect groovy:latest | jq -r '.[].Created'
```

This would give me the creation timestamp

```
docker image remove groovy:latest || true
docker image inspect groovy:latest | jq -r '.[].Created'
```

If the image is not locally available the result would be 'Error: No such image: groovy:latest'

I can get a manifest list like so

```
docker image remove groovy:latest
docker manifest inspect groovy:latest
docker images | grep groovy
```

This does not give me a creation timestamp nor should it as [documented in the api](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#get-manifest).

I am unable to get a timestamp without pulling the image.
Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for?

I need the creation timestamp of the image in the remote registry
So that I can cancel a build if no files are newer than the image.

Some more example code - this is not a minimal example and it takes a while to execute. I recommend testing this on an image with only a few layers. The approach has flaws:

1. It does not produce timestamps since the data is not in the manifests
2. In the current form the execution takes longer than pulling the image
3. Due to the long execution time I am not entirely sure the behavior is as intended.
4. Playing with it kills your rate limit

I removed the example since it does not help and playing with it kills your docker rate limit.